# Invariant Violation: "Minified React error #307

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, webpack

We have our own library for all the react components which we use across the apps.

When importing some components from the library in the apps we are getting the Minified React error #307. If we have the same library component in-app it is rendering well.
Some data points:
We have the same version of react and react-dom in both common library and app.
We are not using React hooks.
We are bundling both the common library and app using the webpack.

Your help in this matter would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: In the component library do you have react and reactDom listed as peer dependencies?

Comment: Thanks @DrewReese for your swift response. We do have peer dependencies, still getting issue.
"peerDependencies": {
    "react": "16.8.0",
    "react-dom": "16.8.0"
  }